# Relationship between prime factorization of $n+1$ and $nm+1$

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

My question is largely based on [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173113/relationship-between-prime-factorizations-of-n-and-n1). It seems that the relationship between prime factorization of $n$ and $n+1$ is a hard problem, because ["multiplication and addition do not 'see' each other"](https://mathoverflow.net/a/56525/98386). However, if we hold addition constant and only multiply $n$ by another integer $m>1$, does the problem become easier?

Comment: No, I don't think there's a direct conclusion about the factorization you can make of one number based off the other, besides the fact that $\gcd(n+1,mn+1)=\gcd(n+1,m-1)$ (which doesn't say that much either)

Comment: Many factorizations would become much easier if this would be possible. I agree with vrugtehagel that there is no useful relation in general.