# Erdös said that math is not ready for the $3x+1$ problem. What is the reasoning for that?

Tags: intuition, collatz-conjecture

I know the Collatz conjecture is dangerous ground and laymen should not be playing here. Please bear with me.

I'm interpreting Erdös' sentence as, we are lacking tools to tackle such kind of problems. My guess is the problem was tried to be solved with methods of most/all fields and no progress was made.

In 2019 Alex Kontorovich [outlined](https://twitter.com/AlexKontorovich/status/1172715174786228224) an idea to construct a counterexample, although the meat is still missing. (Not sure whether this is his or an older idea)

My question is:

- Is Erdös's claim still valid? And was my interpretation of his sentence right?
- Nobody knows this so please provide a reasoning: What are methods/fields which are most promising to be close to a solution?
- Are there similar ideas like Alex Kontorovich's one?

Comment: You're overthinking it. It was an offhand remark which I would wager was made in jest. Erdös was a highly accomplished mathematician, working at the forefront of various fields, and problems similar to Collatz were very much in his playground. I suppose he came to the determination that the current methods of mathematics were simply not sufficient to attack the problem. As of 2020, his view has been vindicated.

Comment: Remember when Erdös offered the price, the amount of processing power in computers was very slow (late 70s and early 80s). Today every home has one or every person have a trillion times faster processor on their handheld phone). Personally if a computer or cluster of computers don't find a counterexample by the end of this decade I think we can prove it using other methods. My belief is that we should be able to prove that the problem is undecidable if and only if we are unable to prove that it is true; by combining methods in graph theory in computer science and topology in mathematics.

Comment: I agree with Erdoes. Noone has the slightest idea how this conjecture can be proven, and the computational power is utterly useless in such cases. The Catalan conjecture has been solved with combining massive computational power and mathematical arguments, but the Collatz conjecture is too dynamical. Of course, I do not (and cannot) claim that it cannot be cracked at all, but I believe that a proof will not be found within the next few decades. Maybe, it is even a case of Goedel's incompleteness theorem, and we need a theory stronger than ZFC to solve it.

Comment: A counterexample would be very surprising (almost no mathematician has serious doubts about this conjecture). But it would show that we have to be careful to draw conclusions too early. At least there are heuristics for the conjecture that indicate its truth.

Comment: @Peter I don't think all mathematicians think this conjecture is correct. Maybe someone "disproved (?)" the hypothesis and is still hiding from us. Who knows! You probably know the history of the 6th question of the 1988 IMO Olympiads. I'm not making analogy. I mean, anything can happen at any time. This is mathematics.

Comment: $1)$ I said "almost no ..." and "...serious doubts..."  $2)$ If someone had found a counterexample, he/she would very probably have published it becuase this would already be enough to become famous. $3)$ yes, surprises in mathematics are always possible, but I did not claim that there cannot be a counterexample. I only said that there are indications for the truth, and that I doubt that a solution occurs soon (including a possible disproof)

Comment: @Peter I can't share the idea of being famous. Not everyone in Russia even knows Perelman.. It's best to wait.

Comment: I am astonished that someone seriously wants to construct a counterexample. But since this would be much more exciting than a proof of the conjecture, I wish him good luck.

Comment: Perelman actually became famous , but if I understood the history of his proof correctly, there were some doubts. Does anyone know whether the proof is now fully accepted ?

Comment: @Peter  Yes Peter. Status of the Poincare Conjecture: Proved https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Poincare+Conjecture

Comment: Wikipedia apparently agrees this entry.

Answer (score 2):

The Collatz conjecture is closely linked to the prime factorization of consecutive integers, i.e., the ''missing link'' between additive and multiplicative number theory.

In particular, we still don't know an explicit relation between the prime factors of the positive integer $n+1$ given the prime factorization of $n$.

You can find more info about this [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173113/relationship-between-prime-factorizations-of-n-and-n1/2425117#2425117).